# Rails: STI with roles and HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, sti

In the app I am working with here are the `User` models...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles 
end

class Athlete < User 
end

class HighSchoolCoach < User 
end
```

A user can have a role of `SchoolAdmin` which grants them access to an admin dashboard of administering Athletes. The `STI` of `HighSchoolCoach` is a user type that has other kinds of features along with giving them access to a dashboard of athletes that they coach. Now, I am trying to build it so that a `User` with a role of `SchoolAdmin` can also be assigned as a `HighSchoolCoach`, just not sure how to do it..

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have to use habtm? Much prefer has_many though

Comment: I suppose I don't have too, I can always change it out. Good thing about Rails, those kinds of things are simple :)